# @Temporal to format date in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, date, format

I have a date parameter in DB model and I want to retrive the date in this format "dd/MM/yyyy". I have annotation on getter like below:

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}
```

However, I receive date in format yyyy-MM-dd. It seems that the @Temporal annotations formats to 'yyyy-MM-dd' but the DateTimeFormat has no effect.

rest response:

```
{
   "id":"token1497340427913",
   "status":"finished",
   "startDate":null,
   "endDate":null,
   "created":"2017-06-13",
   "modified":"2017-06-13"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use @JsonFormat, look the chapter 3.2 http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") 
private Date created;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this.
You can edit it to soothwhat you want to achieve

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdAt;
@PrePersist
protected void prePersist() {
    if (this.createdAt == null) createdAt = new Date();
}
```